# Hazelcast kubernetes discovery using API with envoy proxy as sidecar

Tags: kubernetes, hazelcast, envoyproxy

We are running hazelcast in embedded mode and the application is running in kubernetes cluster. We are using Kubernetes API for discovery.

It was all working fine and now we just started using `envoy` as sidecar for SSL. Now for both `inbound` and `outbound` on TCP at `hazelcast` port `5701` we have enabled TLS in envoy but are yet to do changes for kubernetes API call.

Right now we are getting below Exception :

> "class":"com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.DiscoveryJoiner","thread_name":"main","type":"log","data_version":2,"description":"[10.22.69.149]:5701
>   [dev] [3.9.4] Operation: [get]  for kind: [Endpoints]  with name:
>   [servicename]  in namespace: [namespace] 
>   failed.","stack_trace":"j.n.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL
>   message, plaintext connection?\n\tat
>   s.s.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:710)\n\tat
>   s.s.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:527)\n\tat
>   s.s.s.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:975)\n\tat
>   s.s.s.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)\n\tat
>   s.s.s.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)\n\tat
>   s.s.s.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)\n\tat
>   o.i.c.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:281)\n\tat
>   o.i.c.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:251)\n\tat
>   o.i.c.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:151)\n\tat

Can someone help with the overall changes which should be needed for Hazelcast k8s discovery using APIs with envoy as sidecar ?

Comment: Could you provide more information, some configuration YAMLs, etc

Comment: Please also check this: https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes/issues/160

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an example config below for how to deploy Hazelcast with Envoy sidecar and use it with mTLS.

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes/issues/118#issuecomment-553588983

If you want to achieve the same with an embedded architecture, you need to create a headless kubernetes service besides your microservice's kubernetes service. Then you need to give headless service name to hazelcast-kubernetes plugin **service-name** parameter.

You can find more info on hazelcast-kubernetes plugin [README.md](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-kubernetes/blob/master/README.md) file.

**EDIT:**
Hazelcast-Istio-SpringBoot step-by-step guide can be found [here](https://github.com/hazelcast-guides/hazelcast-istio).

Comment: Hi Mesut, I am facing the error - "DNS lookup for serviceDns '{service}.{namespace}.svc.cluster.local' failed: name not found" . I also tried nslookup from one of the pods, but that too didn't work. Any pointers ?

Comment: I suggest to follow that guide. Otherwise, I need your configuration to see what is happening.
https://github.com/hazelcast-guides/hazelcast-istio

Comment: there was a issue with "selector.app" in headless service. Now the "Members {size:2, ver:2}" logs correctly showing the IPs of both the pods.